# mutliprocess.Proccess(args) : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, python-multiprocessing

So this error has beeen confusing me for the past 30 minutes and I am out of options.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub_array_index = 0
    for i in range(requested_threads):
        i = mp.Process(target=check_url, args=(sub_array_index))
        i.start
        threads.append(i)
        array_index += 1

    for i in threads:
        i.join()
```

when I run this snippet of code I get

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

as an error.

I am trying to use

```
 sub_array_index
```

as an index for accessing a sub array that has been split by

```
numpy.array_split(<array name>, <number of sub arrays)
```

is there anything I'm missing?

I have tried:

- Replacing `args=(sub_array_index)`  with `args=(<a solid int value>)`
- I have tried not incrementing the value and leaving it static when called.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be missing a comma to make the `args` a tuple:

```
i = mp.Process(target=check_url, args=(sub_array_index,))
```

Otherwise the parenthesis won't do a thing and indeed it will be a single number

Answer (score 1):

The `args` parameter is a tuple, therefore it is interpreting `sub_array_index` as a `tuple`.

Do `args=((sub_array_index,))`